# How do i remove module's data from Orchard database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, orchardcms

i have installed a module and after the migration and creating tables in `Orchard.sdf` i want to clear all tables and rollback all changes that the migration did.

I dropped the tables but i guess some metadata should be removed.

how we can clear a modules data completely?
thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A complete uninstall involves deleting the database tables and rows that are associated with your module's name, the names of its features, and of its namespaces. Here is a process that worked for us.

1: Run [orchard.exe](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Using-the-command-line-interface) > package uninstall Orchard.Module.MyModuleName

2: Then, open SQL Server Management Studio and drop the following database table(s) that are associated with your module.

```
MyModuleName_MyFeatureNameRecord
```

3: Do a wildcard search of the following table columns. Be sure to search for MyModuleName, MyNamespaceName, MyFeatureName, etc. You will eventually delete all these rows, but not yet.

```
SELECT *  FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord  WHERE Name LIKE '%%'
SELECT *  FROM Settings_ContentTypeDefinitionRecord  WHERE Name LIKE '%%'
SELECT *  FROM Settings_ContentPartDefinitionRecord  WHERE Name LIKE '%%'
SELECT *  FROM Settings_ShellFeatureRecord  WHERE Name LIKE '%%'
SELECT *  FROM Settings_ShellFeatureStateRecord  WHERE Name LIKE '%%'
SELECT *  FROM Orchard_Framework_DataMigrationRecord  WHERE DataMigrationClass LIKE '%%'
```

4: From the search results above, make a note of the Id values of rows in these tables.

```
Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord.Id
Settings_ContentTypeDefinitionRecord.Id
```

5: Now that you have recorded Id, delete the rows that you found in step 3 above.

6: Using the Ids collected in step 4, delete the rows from the following tables.

```
SELECT * FROM Settings_ContentTypePartDefinitionRecord 
    WHERE ContentTypeDefinitionRecord_Id IN()

SELECT * FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord 
    WHERE ContentType_id IN ()
```

That's what worked for me.

Comment: seems to me, you should also delete values from `Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord` where `ContentItemRecord_id` = `Orchard_Framework_ContentItemRecord.id` for known ContentTypes

Answer (score 5):

I don’t know if there is a proper way to do that, but cleaning up **Orchard_Framework_DataMigrationRecord** should be enough: datamigration checks this table to find the current feature version, if there is already an entry you may not be able to re-enable the feature. Also check **Settings_ShellFeatureRecord**, **Settings_ShellFeatureStateRecord**, **Settings_ContentPartDefinitionRecord** and **Settings_ContentTypeDefinitionRecord**.

Finally, there may be many references in other tables but I think nothing dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a SQL Query snippet that makes this easier if you use table prefixes with tenants.

```
USE DatabaseName
DECLARE @moduleName varchar(255);
DECLARE @tableName varchar(255);
DECLARE @tablePrefix varchar(255);

SET @moduleName = '%Orchard.YourModule%';
SET @tablePrefix = 'YourTablePrefix';

SET @tableName = @tablePrefix + '_Orchard_Framework_ContentTypeRecord';
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SELECT @sql = ' SELECT * ' +
              ' FROM dbo.' + quotename(@tableName) +
              ' WHERE Name LIKE @moduleName'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@moduleName varchar(255)', @moduleName;

SET @tableName = @tablePrefix + '_Settings_ContentTypeDefinitionRecord';
SELECT @sql = ' SELECT * ' +
              ' FROM dbo.' + quotename(@tableName) +
          ' WHERE Name LIKE @moduleName'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@moduleName varchar(255)', @moduleName;

SET @tableName = @tablePrefix + '_Settings_ContentPartDefinitionRecord';
SELECT @sql = ' SELECT * ' +
              ' FROM dbo.' + quotename(@tableName) +
          ' WHERE Name LIKE @moduleName'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@moduleName varchar(255)', @moduleName;

SET @tableName = @tablePrefix + '_Settings_ShellFeatureRecord';
SELECT @sql = ' SELECT * ' +
              ' FROM dbo.' + quotename(@tableName) +
              ' WHERE Name LIKE @moduleName'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@moduleName varchar(255)', @moduleName;

SET @tableName = @tablePrefix + '_Settings_ShellFeatureStateRecord';
SELECT @sql = ' SELECT * ' +
              ' FROM dbo.' + quotename(@tableName) +
              ' WHERE Name LIKE @moduleName'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@moduleName varchar(255)', @moduleName;

SET @tableName = @tablePrefix + '_Orchard_Framework_DataMigrationRecord';
SELECT @sql = ' SELECT * ' +
              ' FROM dbo.' + quotename(@tableName) +
              ' WHERE DataMigrationClass LIKE @moduleName'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@moduleName varchar(255)', @moduleName;
```